# Identify files preventing Net Use /Delete

Tags: windows, networking, file-sharing, net-use

Sometimes when executing

```
net use /delete (\\connection or drive)
```

I get

```
There are open files and/or incomplete directory searches pending on the connection
```

How can I find/identify those files? (or dir searches).

I've found tons of advice on how to force the connection closed, and advice on how to identify *incoming* connections to my shares (typically via Computer Management GUI, Shared Folders, Open Files).  But I can't find any clue on how to locate my own outgoing file connections in this way.